# 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'OUTPUT

Tags: sql, mariadb

i'm new to SQL and i'm getting this error for this query :

```
Insert into admin.MaintenanceWindows (StartTime, StopTime, Message, Status, AccessibilityLabel) 

OUTPUT inserted.StartTime

values ('2022-12-17 03:47:00', '2022-12-18 03:47:00', 'Testdeclare', 'Scheduled', 'TEST');
```

i also tried

```
DECLARE @inserted table (StartTime int);

insert into admin.MaintenanceWindows (StartTime, StopTime, Message, Status, AccessibilityLabel) 
output inserted.StartTime into @inserted
values ('2022-12-17 03:47:00', '2022-12-18 03:47:00', 'Testdeclare', 'Scheduled', 'TEST');

select * from @inserted;
```

i get error:- Declare is not valid along with Output is not valid

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'OUTPUT inserted.StartTime values ('2022-12-17 03:47:00', '2022-12-18 03:47:00...' at line 2

Comment: Why did you use the `SQL Server` tag if you target MariaDB? Those are completely different products.

Comment: Are you sure is is sql-server?

Comment: This is tagged sql-server, but you title and post talke about MariaDB ?

Comment: `OUTPUT` is a SQL Server feature. The equivalent functionality in MariaDB is provided by [the RETURNING clause](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/insertreturning/)

Comment: Database products offer only basic support for the SQL standard. *All* databases have custom syntax and features that don't work in other databases. You can't just use one product's syntax to do the same thing in another product. In this case, `OUTPUT` in SQL Server is used to *return* the data changes by an operation, eg a trigger, a default value, an AUTOINCREMENT constraint. The same thing in MariaDB, PostgreSQL and Oracle is done using `RETURNING`. MySQL doesn't have this feature at all

Comment: What are you trying to do? `OUTPUT inserted.StartTime` is returning the same value specified in the VALUES clause, something the caller already knows

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you tried to achive by the output term, but it looks like the right query should be without `OUTPUT inserted.StartTime`

Just-

```
-- create
CREATE TABLE MaintenanceWindows (
  StartTime  DATETIME NOT NULL, 
  StopTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
  Message TEXT NOT NULL,
  Status TEXT NOT NULL,
  AccessibilityLabel TEXT NOT NULL
);

-- insert

INSERT INTO  MaintenanceWindows values ('2022-12-17 03:47:00', '2022-12-18 03:47:00', 'Testdeclare', 'Scheduled', 'TEST') RETURNING StartTime ;
```

And the result from real compiler online (thanks to https://onecompiler.com/).
I changed your table from admin.MaintenanceWindows to MaintenanceWindows.
If you still have a compilation error, something is wrong with your table or with the data you are trying to insert into it.

[image: from real compiler]

Comment: That won't work if the OP actually wants to return the modified data. That's what `OUTPUT` does in SQL Server

Comment: Ok, I added returning clause, base on the question which is not clear if it was the original meaning

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'RETURNING StartTime' at line 5

Comment: @yadavenderyadav Please check it now